# Multiplicative structure on Čech–Alexander complexes

Tags: simplicial-stuff, tensor-products, chain-complexes, cech-cohomology

I have the following basic question on Čech–Alexander complexes.

Let $R$ be a ring and $A$ be an $R$-algebra. To this datum one can attach a cosimplicial ring which assigns to an object $[n]=\{0,1,\dotsc,n\}$ of the category of totally ordered finite sets $\Delta$ the ring $A^{\otimes [n]}=A\otimes_R \cdots \otimes_R A$ (*the Čech nerve* of $R\to A$). To this cosimplicial ring, we can consider its *Moore Complex*, also called in this situation *the Čech–Alexander complex*:
$$(\mathrm{CA})\quad 0\to A\xrightarrow{\partial^1} A\otimes_R A \xrightarrow{\partial^2}A\otimes_R A\otimes_R A\xrightarrow{\partial^3} \cdots$$
with $A^{\otimes [n]}$ in degree $n$ and
$$ \partial^n(a_1\otimes\dotsb \otimes a_n)=\sum_{i=0}^n{(-1)^i(a_1\otimes \dotsb \otimes a_i\otimes 1 \otimes a_{i+1}\otimes \dotsb \otimes a_n)}$$

> **My Question:** Is there a canonical multiplicative structure on $(\mathrm{CA})$? If yes, what is the formula? Is this obtained by the maps $A^{\otimes [i]}\otimes A^{\otimes [j]}\to A^{\otimes [i+j]}$, $(a_0\otimes \cdots \otimes a_i)\otimes (b_0\otimes \cdots \otimes b_j)\mapsto a_0\otimes \cdots \otimes (a_i b_0)\otimes \cdots \otimes b_j$?

For instance, I do not see how one can multiply two elements in degree one to obtain one of degree two; that is two elements in $A\otimes_R A$ to get an element in $A\otimes_R A\otimes_R A$. This looks inconveniently shifted….

**EDIT:** If I am inclined to think that there is a multiplicative structure, this is by transport of structure from the one of cohomology theories on indiscrete/chaotic sites; e.g. as described by Kedlaya in [Notes on prismatic cohomology](https://kskedlaya.org/prismatic/sec_prismatic-site.html#subsection-44).

Comment: I know it's not terribly important, but, since your $[n]$ has $n + 1$ elements, I'm confused what $A^{\otimes[n]}$ means.  Does it have $n$ or $n + 1$ tensor factors?

Comment: @LSpice Thanks for your comment! $A^{\otimes [n]}$ indeed has $n+1$ tensor factors (and lives in degree $n$).

Comment: I think the formula of 20.25.3.2 here should apply? https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01FP

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet Thanks for your comment! Are you able to unravel what it means in this particular situation?